# How to check if property exists in Type in an extension method?

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I frequently have code like this:

```
var stRecs = db.<someTable>
             .Where(a => a.DepID == depID)
```

to select a single record, however if `depID == 0` I would like to get back all records.

I was thinking about creating an extension method "WhereDepID_OrAll", like

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereDepID_OrAll<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
        where T: // is what?
{
    if(depID > 0) { return source.Where(a => a.depID == depID); }
    else return source.Where(a => a);
}
```

Now my basic question is:
I have several tables with depID - how do I set the `Where T:` ?
How would the method determine, whether the table has depID?

A better approach to the underlying problem?

Comment: Perhaps you should create an interface `IHaveDepId`, and let your tables inherit that interface :) then `T : IHaveDepId`. It would be nicer i think

Comment: @JensKloster no. You can't use an interface property in a linq to entity query.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus why not? depending on your approch - e.g. code first or model first, there are verious ways to modify the clr classes.

Comment: @JensKloster see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613701/expression-generated-based-on-interface

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I see your point. The DB table would have to own an attribute named *exacly* `DepID` (in this case)

Comment: @JensKloster well I'm not sure about what happens "under the hood", to be honest, but I'm quite sure this will raise an Exception...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first glance, the reaction would be : create an  interface

```
public interface ObjectWithDepartmentInterface {
    int depID;
}
```

make all the entities using this depId implementing this interface, and use

```
where T : ObjectWithDepartmentInterface
```

but linq to entities doesn't accept properties from interfaces in query... See for example : [Expression generated based on interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613701/expression-generated-based-on-interface)

So the only way would to make your entities with a depId inheriting from a common entity (probably abstract) with a depId property.

And use this abstract entity as the

```
where T:
```

An easier (but uglier way) could be to not add a constraint on T, build the predicate in the method, and throw an exception in bad cases.

```
if (typeof(T).GetProperty("depId") == null)
   throw InvalidOperationException (string.Format("{0}" doesn't have a depId property, typeof(T).Name))
```

**EDIT**

But maybe it's not a problem of depId as a common property
Then

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereExistsOrAll<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, int value)
        where T: // is what?
{
    if (value == 0)
    return source;
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "m");
    Expression member = parameter;
    member = Expression.Property(member, propertyName);
    member = Expression.Equals(member, Expression.Constant(value));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(member, new[]{parameter});
    return source.Where(lambda);
}
```

usage

```
var stRecs = db.<someTable>.WhereExistsOrAll("depId", depId);
```

**EDIT 2**

Another way would be to parse the Predicate to get the "constant" value

something like that

```
public static IQueryable<T> GetAllOrRestrict<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
       var expression = predicate.Body as BinaryExpression;

       var rightPart = expression.Right as MemberExpression;
       var value = GetValue(rightPart);
       var test = value.ToString();
       int val;
       if (Int32.TryParse(value.ToString(), out val))
       {
           if (val != 0)
               return queryable.Where(predicate);
       }

       return queryable;
}

private static object GetValue(MemberExpression member)
{
     var objectMember = Expression.Convert(member, typeof(object));
     var getterLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(objectMember);
     var getter = getterLambda.Compile();
     return getter();
}
```

usage

```
var stRecs = db.<someTable>.GetAllOrRestrict(m => m.depID == depId);
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's not particularly fashionable, but isn't this exactly what [the Query Builder methods in Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896238.aspx) are for?

```
var stRecs = db.<someTable>
             .Where("it.DepID == @depID OR @depID = 0", 
                    new ObjectParameter("depID", depID));
```

This works on any `someTable` such that it has a column named `DepID`. It can of course be made an extension method:

```
public static ObjectQuery<T> WhereIdEqualOrAll<T>(this ObjectQuery<T> q, int depID)
    where T : class
{
    return q.Where("it.DepID = @id OR @id = 0", new ObjectParameter("id", id));
}
```

to be invoked thus:

```
var stRecs = db.<someTable>.WhereIdEqualOrAll(depID);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an interface:

```
public interface IInterface
{
   int depId;
}
```

Which will force `T` to inherit from `IInterface` and implement `depId`.

Then you can add it to the extension:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereDepID_OrAll<T>(this IQueryable<T> source) where T: IInterface
{

}
```

Comment: You can't use an interface property in linq to entities...  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326462/linq-to-entities-through-interface-property or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613701/expression-generated-based-on-interface

Answer (score 0):

Use an interface, then build an expression tree manually, referencing the actual class.

Answer (score 0):

Raphaels Edit 2 did the job!

small edition:
How could I include NULL-Values if a DepID is present?

I like to return all Departments with ID == x OR ID == NULL

Maybe with an additional bool includeNullValues)

```
public static IQueryable<T> GetAllOrRestrict<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable,
 Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, 
 bool includeNullValues)
    {
        var expression = predicate.Body as BinaryExpression;

        var rightPart = expression.Right as MemberExpression;
        var value = GetValue(rightPart);
        var test = value.ToString();
        int val;
        if (Int32.TryParse(value.ToString(), out val))
        {
            if (val != 0)
            {
                if (includeNullValues)
                {
                    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T),"m");

                    return queryable.Where(predicate) <====HOW to " || depID == null) ???
                }
                else
                {
                return queryable.Where(predicate);
                }
            }
        }

        return queryable;
    }
```

Comment: you'd rather ask another question, for clarity purpose... Anyway, you mean depId (or any property used) could be a `Nullable<int>` ? Or that it's part of a navigation property, which could be null (something like `(m => m.MyEntity.DepId == depId)`

Comment: Then you have to recreate the Expression for all the left part of the predicate... (do-able, of course, but more complicated). But you could also just do `var stRecs = db.<someTable>.GetAllOrRestrict(m => (m.depID ?? depId) == depId);` (which is less "nice", I must admit)

Comment: I am baffled - this works - and I have to admit, I dont understand the (m.depID ?? depId) == depId part...Oh well... I will have to dig deeper into bitwise, I guess! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: well that's not bitwise, it's the `coalesce` operator. It means : `if m.depId == 0 then take the value of your parameter`, which does the same as you want ;)